# 2 Timers at the same time

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, timer, swift2

I need to use 2 timers at the same time: one for a session and one for exercices.

The one for exercices can be either a timer or a count down depending on the exercices.

I used this class  for the 2 timers but I have a delay of 1s: I think it's a problem of thread. I tried to dispatch but not working.

Moreover the class is not accurate since refresh may take longer than specified, based on the available resources.

Do you have a solution to resolve my issue: having 2 accurate timers at same which can be timer or count down ?

Thank you for your help

```
public class Chronometer: NSObject {

//
// MARK: - Private Properties

private var startTime = NSTimeInterval(0)
private var accumulatedTime = NSTimeInterval(0)
private var elapsedSinceLastRefresh = NSTimeInterval(0)
private var timer = NSTimer()

//
// MARK: - Public Properties

public var elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval {
    return elapsedSinceLastRefresh + accumulatedTime
}

/// The Time Interval to refresh the chronometer. The default is 1 second
public var refreshInterval = NSTimeInterval(1)

/// Determines a time limit for this Chronometer
public var timeLimit: NSTimeInterval?

/// Optional Block that gets called on each refresh of the specified time interval.
/// If this class needs to update UI, make sure that the UI class are made in the
///  main thread, or dispatched into it.
public var updateBlock: ((NSTimeInterval, NSTimeInterval?) -> ())?

/// Optional Block that gets called when the chronometer reach its limit time
public var completedBlock: (() -> ())?

//
// MARK: - Initializers

///
/// A convenience initializer that allow specifying the refresh interval
/// :param: refreshInterval The desired refresh interval
///
public convenience init(refreshInterval: NSTimeInterval) {
    self.init()
    self.refreshInterval = refreshInterval
}

///
/// A convenience initializer that allow specifying the refesh interval and update block
/// :param: refreshInterval The desired refresh interval
/// :param: updateBlock The update block to be called on each refresh
///
public convenience init(refreshInterval: NSTimeInterval, updateBlock: (NSTimeInterval, NSTimeInterval?) -> ()) {
    self.init()
    self.refreshInterval = refreshInterval
    self.updateBlock = updateBlock
}

//
// MARK: - Internal Methods

///
/// Refresh the timer, calling the update block to notify the tracker about the new value.
///
func refreshTime() {
    // Calculate the new time
    var refreshTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
    self.elapsedSinceLastRefresh = (refreshTime - startTime)

    // Calculates the remaining time if applicable
    var remainingTime: NSTimeInterval? = nil
    if self.timeLimit != nil {
        remainingTime = self.timeLimit! - elapsedTime
    }

    // If an update block is specified, then call it
    self.updateBlock?(elapsedTime, remainingTime)

    // If the chronometer is complete, then call the block and
    if let limit = self.timeLimit {
        if self.elapsedTime >= limit {
            self.stop()
            self.completedBlock?()
        }
    }
}

//
// MARK: - Public Methods

///
/// Set a time limit for this chronometer
///
public func setLimit(timeLimit: NSTimeInterval, withCompletionBlock completedBlock: () -> ()) {
    self.timeLimit = timeLimit
    self.completedBlock = completedBlock
}

///
/// Start the execution of the Cronometer.
/// Start will take place using accumulated time from the last session. 
/// If the Cronometer is running the call will be ignored.
///
public func start() {
    if !timer.valid {
        // Create a new timer
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(self.refreshInterval,
            target: self,
            selector: "refreshTime",
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: true)

        // Set the base date
        startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
    }
}

///
/// Stops the execution of the Cronometer.
/// Keeps the accumulated value, in order to allow pausing of the chronometer, and
///  to keep "elapsedTime" property value available for the user to keep track.
///
public func stop() {
    timer.invalidate()
    accumulatedTime = elapsedTime
    elapsedSinceLastRefresh = 0
}

///
/// Resets the Cronometer.
/// This method will stop chronometer if it's running. This is necessary since 
///  the class is not thread safe.
///
public func reset() {
    timer.invalidate()
    elapsedSinceLastRefresh = 0
    accumulatedTime = 0
}
}
```

In my UIViewController, in the viewDidLoad():

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) { [unowned self] in
        self.chronometerWorkout = Chronometer(refreshInterval: NSTimeInterval(0.01)) {
            (elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval, remainingTime: NSTimeInterval?) in

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                if let r = remainingTime {
                    self.counterView?.chronoWorkoutLabel.text = r.getFormattedInterval(miliseconds: false)
                } else {
                    self.secondsChronoWorkout = elapsedTime
                    self.counterView?.chronoWorkoutLabel.text = elapsedTime.getFormattedInterval(miliseconds: false)

                }
            }

        }
    }



    self.chronometerExo = Chronometer(refreshInterval: NSTimeInterval(0.01)) {
        (elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval, remainingTime: NSTimeInterval?) in
        if let r = remainingTime {
            self.counterView?.chronoExoLabel.text = r.getFormattedInterval(miliseconds: false)
            self.graphicView.yValues[self.selectedRow] = Double(remainingTime!)
            self.counterView?.circularTimerProgressView.progress = CGFloat(remainingTime!)

        } else {
            self.secondsChronoExo = elapsedTime
            self.counterView?.chronoExoLabel.text = elapsedTime.getFormattedInterval(miliseconds: false)
            self.graphicView.yValues[self.selectedRow] = Double(elapsedTime)
            self.counterView?.circularTimerProgressView.progress = CGFloat(elapsedTime)

        }
    }
```

**UPDATED:**

```
var startWorkOutDate:CFAbsoluteTime!
var startExoTime:CFAbsoluteTime!
var timeReference:Double!


func updateTimerLabels() {

    let elapsedTimeWorkOut = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startWorkOutDate
    self.counterView?.chronoWorkoutLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f",elapsedTimeWorkOut)

    let startExoTime = self.startExoTime ?? 0.0
    let elapsedTimeExo = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startExoTime

    if timeReference != 0 {

        if elapsedTimeExo <= timeReference {
            let remainingTimeExo = timeReference - elapsedTimeExo
            self.counterView?.chronoExoLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f",remainingTimeExo)
        }

    } 

}


func startTimers(indexPath: NSIndexPath){      

    ...

    if self.startWorkoutChronometer == false {
        startWorkOutDate = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

        self.startWorkoutChronometer = true
        self.startExoChronometer = true

        _ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTimerLabels"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    if self.startExoChronometer == true {
        if timeReference != 0 {
            if self.graphicView.yValues[selectedRow] == timeReference {
                startExoTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

            } else {
                timeReference = Double(Int(self.graphicView.yValues[selectedRow]))
            }   
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider not using 1 `NSTimer` instance per timer. Use an `NSTimer`, or maybe even display link' only to trigger updates to the UI.

For your timers, just record the start time as an `NSDate` and the timer type. Provide a method to ask for the current time, or display value. The timer can then calculate that on the fly based on the current device time.

In this way you will have no slip or offset and you can update the UI as fast as you like.

Comment: I still have one second delay when one of the timer is in a countdown mode. I have updated my 1st post with the new code. Where is my pb ? I think the conversion to a String make the delay

Comment: Delay where? You should store the reference to the timer (so you can stop it). When is `startTimers` called?

Comment: The `startTimers` is called from an UITableView (selected row). The `timeReference` is taken from an array of times with the index of the row. The delay is observed at the beginning betwwen the workout timer and the exo timer, ie 00:02 for the workout and 00:17 for the exo (timeReference=20).  The reference to the timer can be stored in the user info that's it ?

Comment: The timer should be stored in the view controller. Ideally you would separate the timer from this logic and initially you can just let it run the whole time the VC is on screen. I don't really get your usage of `timeReference`. I'd have an object for each 'timer' and store the start `NSDate` and `duration` in each. At the moment I get the impression you aren't separating logic and data between the model, view and controller very well and it's leading to confusion and complexity...

Comment: Ok If I understand, it's better to set the timer in the viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear which call the `updateLabels` method ?  I have an uitableview with different exercices with different times per row of the `UITableView`. So when I select a row I want to start the workout timer and an exercice workout which get the timeReference of the exercice. Each time I select a row the exercice's timer must be reinitialized and start again. I don't understand: " I'd have an object for each 'timer' and store the start NSDate and duration in each" . Is it more cleared ?

Comment: That's a start for the timer, yes. An object to represent the timer means you can create and configure it and then throw it away when you're done. And you can have 1 for exercise and one for workout. This would replace the complexity of `startWorkoutChronometer`, `startExoChronometer` and `timeReference` and how they work (or don't) together

Comment: OK. I see. But it's equivalent to the `public class Chronometer: NSObject` describe above no ?

Comment: Similar, but a lot simpler and with more organised responsibility: no timer, a single `NSDate` for the start and a single `Int` (or `Float`) for the duration